# How to implement SPF Macros?

Tags: dns, spf

I created SPF record for my domain like:

```
v=spf1 include:%{i}._ip.%{h}._ehlo.%{d}._spf.example.com ~all
```

Now I want to send mail from ip: `192.0.2.123` and `198.51.100.234`, and domain `xyz.example`

My SPF record will work like this:

```
192.0.2.123._ip.ehlo._ehlo.xyz.example._spf.example.com

198.51.100.234._ip.ehlo._ehlo.xyz.example._spf.example.com
```

Will I need to create 2(multiple) different DNS records in `example.com` or it will work in a single DNS?

If it works in a 1 DNS record lookup then please let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your macros generate DNS names that are used for `include`, yes, each will need a corresponding TXT record. You could possibly match a single record by using a wildcard, along the lines of `*._ip.ehlo._ehlo.xyz.example._spf.example.com`, but that would undermine the point of having the macro in the first place. I'm curious why you would need such a fine-grained structure that can't be generalised.

Comment: Actually I want send mails from some ips and some services (like google,mailchimp etc.) so my DNS lookup is increased by more than 10. I want to create micro SPF. If I do flattening then if google spf will update then my records are outdated. How I will resolve this probelm?

Comment: I would go with a more generalised SPF, don't flatten anything, but use stronger DKIM & DMARC settings. Even with SPF includes, you should not be hitting 10 lookups anyway - why do you have so many? Alternatively, split your message sources so you don't have to use all sources for everything, for example use a subdomain for your mailing lists. Macros also have a danger that they don't play well with DNS caches, so you may be slowing everything down.